# RegEx $0 substitution cannot manipulated (e.g. converted to upper-case)

Tags: c#, regex, regexp-replace

Trying to understand why I cannot manipulate the $0 substitution value when working with RegEx in .Net Core. Here is my full code:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = "part1-part2-part3";
            var pattern = "-p";
            var regex = new Regex(pattern);
            var result1 = regex.Replace(input, "$0".ToUpper());
            Console.WriteLine(result1);

            //Output is this:
            //part1-part2-part3
            //Would expect this:
            //part1-Part2-Part3
        }
    }
```

So why doesn't "$0".ToUpper() work here? And what would be way to achieve this in RegEx (capitalize all first letters after each hyphen).

Comment: Because `"$0".ToUpper()` is already evaluated, it's not an expression that will be evaluated for each match, instead it is evaluated once, before the Regex is executed, and the result of `"$0".ToUpper()` is `"$0"`. You should look at the overload for `Replace` that takes a `MatchEvaluator` delegate.

Comment: A simple variant would be `regex.Replace(input, ma => ma.Value.ToUpper())`